# Big O notation of nested loops

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, nested-loops

```js
function compressBoxesTwice(box1, box2) {
  box1.forEach(function (boxes) {
    console.log(box1);
    box2.forEach(function (boxes) {
      console.log(box2);
    })
  })
}

compressBoxesTwice();
```

What will be the **Big O notation** for the above function?
nested loops are working on **different inputs**
I read that if nested llops are working on same input then Big O will be O(n*n). But in my case nested are working on different inputs.

Comment: Usually `m` is used if another variable is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the outer loop loops through n elements and inner loop loops through m elements, the Big O notation is O(n*m) or O(nm)

Comment: Yes, one could add that this often would just be considered O(N^2) in the case we consider that N is of similar size to M. In some cases we can avoid that (ie. M << N) so then the distinction becomes more important.